# contar registros de una tabla que esta relacionada con otra

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas tengo esta tabla votantes 
[image: tabla votantes con campo lider_id que se relaciona con la tabla lideres]
[image: tabla lideres]
necesito saber cuantos votantes tiene un líder, intente con esta sentencia

```
"SELECT count(v.lider_id) AS voter_cant 
 FROM votantes v 
 LEFT JOIN lideres l ON l.id = v.lider_id";
```

pero me muestra el total de votantes[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este lider solo tiene 2 votantes y me muestra que tiene 12

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
llamo la funcion asi: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
pero no me dado de ninguna manera

Answer (score 5):

Me parece que el `JOIN` que deberías usar es `INNER JOIN` por:

- Usar `LEFT JOIN` hace que las filas de la tabla izquierda que no tienen una fila relacionada en la tabla de la derecha también se muestren o en este caso también se cuenten para el caso de la función de agregación `COUNT`

Quedando tu consulta así:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.lider_id) AS voter_cant
FROM votantes v
INNER JOIN lideres l ON v.lider_id = l.id;
```

Posterior pudieras agregar un `WHERE` para indicar que solo haga el conteo con base en una condición dada:

```
WHERE v.nombre_completo = "algo";
```

Comment: En realidad con tan solo agregar el `WHERE l.id = 1` (_ID del lider_) en la consulta del `COUNT` bastaría. En otras palabras, para obtener el `COUNT` correcto necesita aplicar el mismo filtro que aplicó en la consulta donde busca los registros.

Comment: ya probe y no me funciono, la sentencia la tengo dentro de una funcion pero no me da

Comment: @MatthewRuizKidman deberías agregar esos dertalles a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte, el código de tu función por ejemplo

Comment: @Marcos como dices esta bien, pero tengo varios lideres con diferentes id, como llamo el id de cada lider en la sentencia sq

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener la cantidad de votantes de cada lider puedes hacer tu consulta de la sgte manera:

```
SELECT COUNT(v.lider_id) AS voter_cant
FROM votantes v
INNER JOIN lideres l ON v.lider_id = l.id
WHERE v.lider_id = l.id;
```

Para mostrar mas datos como el nombre y demas te pedira que agrupes los datos.